# Javafx: How can I bind ComboBox items dynamically to an observablelist updating itself from database

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to bind my javafx comboBox items to an observablelist; when the list updates the combobox items would update as well(add, delete or modify ). I tried to add listener to the combobox items but still get "Not on FX application thread" Exception. Here is my code:

**Model**

```
{
    …
    private ObservableList<String> programList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    …
    some code initialize programList from database
    …

    private ListProperty<String> programListProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>(programList);

    …
    some code update programList periodically
    …

    }
```

And the **Controller**

```
{
    @FXML ComboBox programComboBox;


    model.programListProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        programComboBox.getItems().clear();
        programComboBo.getItems().add(every item in model.programList);
    }));
}
```

Also I tried this way, but neither would work

```
{
    @FXML ComboBox programComboBox;

    programComboBox.itemsproperty().bind(model.programListProperty());

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** This solution makes some assumptions about your implementation, as you have not provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

---

You do not need to use a binding for this. The `ComboBox` uses an `ObservableList` to populate its items. The keyword here is **observable**. This means that when the underlying `List` changes, the `ComboBox` will "see" the changes and update its displayed items automatically.

You initialize the `ComboBox` with the `setItems()` method, passing it an `ObservableList` as a parameter:

`comboBox.setItems(programList);`

From there, any time the `programList` is updated (items added, removed, etc), the `ComboBox` will reflect the changes without any further code needed from you.

---

Review the following complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ComboBoxListenerExample extends Application {

    // This is our ObservableList that will hold our ComboBox items
    private ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Simple ComboBox
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

        // Let's "permanently" set our ComboBox items to the "items" ObservableList. This causes the
        // ComboBox to "observe" the list for changes
        comboBox.setItems(items);

        // Create a button that will reload data from our "database"
        Button button = new Button("Refresh Data");

        // The items.setAll()` method replaces all items in the list with our new list of items
        button.setOnAction(event -> items.setAll(reloadDatabase()));

        root.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, button);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Sample method to simulate reloading the database information
    private List<String> reloadDatabase() {

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            items.add(getRandomWord());
        }
        return items;

    }

    // Just a helper method specific for this example; it simply returns a random word. 
    // This is used to simulate loading new data from the database
    private String getRandomWord() {

        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Left", "Right", "Top", "Bottom");
        Random random = new Random();
        return words.get(random.nextInt(words.size()));
    }
}
```

---

Upon running the example, the `ComboBox` is empty. Each time you click the "Refresh Data" button, the underlying `ObservableList`, `items`, is updated with a new list of random items; the `ComboBox` changes to reflect those changes immediately.

---

**Not on JavaFX Application Thread:**

*Now, what about that error message? There are many questions and answers on StackOverflow that already address that issue, but here's a short explanation:*

I assume you are loading data from the database on a background thread and ***that is good!***  However, you cannot make any changes or updates to the UI from that thread. All UI updates need to be done on the JavaFX Application Thread.

This is very simple to accomplish. When you update the `List` when calling your database method, wrap that update in a `Platform.runLater()` call:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> programList.setAll(yourNewList));
```

This schedules the update to the List to occur on the JFX Application Thread. Problem solved!

Comment: Thank you! This helps me to understand binding, I thought Platform.runLater could only be invoked in a controller, but it can also update data in model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted a MCVE there is only so much we can do to help here is an example of what you are trying to do I did my best to mimic what you already have you will have to see what is not working on your end and correct it but here is an example of what I did its tested and working for me

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Model model = new Model();

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.itemsProperty().bind(model.getProgramListProperty());

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.getChildren().add(comboBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```

Model Class

```
public class Model{

    private ObservableList<String> programList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ListProperty<String> programListProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>(programList);

    Model(){
        updateListFromDatabase();
        continuousDatabaseUpdate();
    }

    ListProperty<String> getProgramListProperty() {
        return programListProperty;
    }

    private void continuousDatabaseUpdate() {
        new Timer().schedule( //Schedule a timer to fire a task at an interval
                new TimerTask() {//Create a new TimerTask that runs a list update
                    @Override
                    public void run() {//What its running
                        //Important my update is wrapped in Platform.runLater so I DON'T block the main thread
                        Platform.runLater(() -> updateListFromDatabase());
                    }
                },
                0,//Delay 0
                2/*Number of seconds*/ * 1000/*turn milliseconds into seconds*/);
    }

    private void updateListFromDatabase(){//Create a list of varying size and changing numbers
        programList.clear();//Clear current list 
        double size = Math.random() * 10 + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            programList.add(String.valueOf(Math.random() * 20 + 1));//Add random values
        }
    }
}
```

**This may not be the optimal solution because we cannot see what you are trying to do in an MCVE you have just posted some code and expected others to fill in the rest**

Also I would not recommend adding a listener to the list I would check if the list needed to be updated whenever you talk to your database. Below is what I was referencing

```
model.programListProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        programComboBox.getItems().clear();
        programComboBo.getItems().add(every item in model.programList);
    }));
```

Otherwise this is the flow of data

> CheckForDatabaseChanges->UpdateList->Listener handles update

VS

> CheckForDatabaseChanges->UpdateList(Have this push the update without the need of the listener)

Unless your database notifies you when it updates in that case your way makes sense I doubt it because you said "some code update programList periodically"  this is why an **MCVE** would've been helpful